# How to use MergeConent Processor in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a Nifi flow where I have multiple rows of data in Json, that for each **row** needs to do the following:

- Split data (EvaluateJsonPath) and take relevant fields for insertion into Database (Mysql).
- Take fields for table A and put them into DB. The
  return value of this action is auto generated ID from table A.
- Take return value from table insertion and merge with table B fields. The return value from table A becomes a reference value in table B so the split row entries become linked.

I have set up flow (see picture) but fail with `MergeContent` processor because I think it does not know how to merge the content correctly. If I have e.g. 200 rows it only merges one row and the rest go into failure. I have read about defragmentation in `Nifi` but have failed to implement that successfully so any input is appreciated.

Flow Chart:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you use the merge processor, the flowfile should have correct attributes such as `fragment.index`, `fragment.identifier`, and `fragment.count`. If your flow files didn't have this, the merge wouldn't work.

Most of the cases, those attributes are created automatically when you split a record. So, simply you can add the split process by using `SplitAvro` before `ConvertAvroToJson`. It will split your query result into row by row and do the things that you want and it will be merged.